# Communication between Android App and Raspberry Pi 3 via a Wlan Router

Tags: android, network-programming, raspberry-pi3

I want to program an Android App that receive real-time sensor data from a ultrasound distance sensor which is connected to a Raspberry Pi 3.

In order to do this my plan is to set up a local area network and connect both, the App and the Pi to the Network via Wlan.
The Sensor collect the data and the raspberry should transmit the data to the App probably on more than just one device.

I've already programed the UI of the App but I don't know how to set up the connection (the specific distance value should be displayed in a textView).

So is a real-time transition possible with this setup? and how do I set the connection? are there any useful tutorials or links form your perspective?

Many thanks for every little help in this matter.

Comment: Dont understand your problem with a connection. You should have a server and a client. And the client connects to the server. After that they can communicate. Please explain better.

Comment: Thanks Greenaps, the problem is that I have zero experience in network programming, so that I wanted to share my idea with people who can evaluate if my idea would work technically and could give me additional advices where I can look up for helpful tutorials or so. My Google research confuses me more than that it helps

Comment: There are several examples on the internet and i think on instuctables also where with a browser on the smartphone or your home pc you can request a web page from the raspberry with a command in the url like `http://192.168.1.12/commands.php?led=on`. Then a led is turned on or off. For that you have to run a webserver on the raspi with the php scripts. All you can find on the internet and is easy installable. After that adapt a script so it understands `?command=getdistance`. If that works you can use the urls in your app with HttpUrlConnection class.

Comment: Think that using wifi over bluetooth is a good idea as then all will work over the internet too and over bigger distances than ten meter.

Answer (score 2):

If I were in your shoes, I'd rather use Bluetooth Low Energy since it's available in both Raspberry Pi 3 and Android devices with (API level 18+).

The Raspberry should act as a Gatt Server, and the android devices indeed as a Gatt client and there's [an awesome API for that](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

Normally, Gatt server can connect to multiple clients. But, if you have to send the sensor's data to a lot of devices, the right choice is to [stream it through the internet.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/architecture/real-time-stream-processing-iot)

For an MVP, I suggest BLE technology, start setting up a Gatt server and connect to it with [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp). Once everything is ok then create your gatt client android app.

Comment: Thanks neogineer, there is just one problem. Requirements to this system is that it should work without an internet connection, because of the company security regulations. And that's the reason why I try to distribute the signal via Wlan in an autarchic network to at least 5 Devices which run the same app

Comment: I guess you'll have to stream data over your own private cloud : 
http://www.orange-business.com/en/blogs/connecting-technology/cloud-data-center/private-cloud-and-the-internet-of-things-a-perfect-match